# Python mouse clicks won't work inside Memu emulator

Tags: python, android-emulator

I would like to build a program in Python that will play a simple Android game for me.  I am using memu android emulator to do this on my pc.  I can use pyautogui to successful move my mouse, but when I click regions inside the memu emulator, nothing happens.

I am running Windows 10.  I did notice I got a permission error with pyautogui.click(), so I fixed this as follows:

```
#  pyautogui Fix

import pyautogui

def click(x=None,y=None,buttonclick=''):
    try:
        if type(x) == None and type(x) == None and len(buttonclick) > 0:
            pyautogui.click(x,y,button=buttonclick)
        elif type(x) != None and type(x) != None:
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
        else:
            pyautogui.click()
    except PermissionError:
        pass

def doubleClick(x=None,y=None,buttonclick=''):
    click(x,y,buttonclick)
    click(x,y,buttonclick)
```

A small sample of what I am trying to do...

```
import os
import pyautogui, pyautoguiFix

mouseSpeed = 0.5

# click icon on memu desktop
pyautogui.moveTo(1271, 379, duration= mouseSpeed)
pyautoguiFix.click()
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Having a similar problem, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your python script as administrator, to do this: right click on your script and click "Run as administrator". It helped me:)

Comment: Wow. Thank you, I will try this. Fingers crossed.